# Splash screen is too fast, I can't see my result of my Fortran program

Tags: fortran

I am newbie to programming. I start write my Hello world in Fortran but the splash screen is very fast. Why can't I see anything? Why is the black screen not showing me: "hello world"?

I see splash screen but it vanishes in the speed of light...

```
program HelloWorld
   write (*,*) 'Hello, world!'   ! This is an inline comment
 end program HelloWorld
```

Comment: @user630738: which is you OS, compiler? How do you compile and execute you programs?

Answer (score 5):

you can try pause at the point you want to stop the program  for example

```
program HelloWorld
   write (*,*) 'Hello, world!'   ! This is an inline comment
   pause
 end program HelloWorld
```

after the 'hello world' was displayed, the cmd windows will still hold on,because the pause function,after check your result, press Enter. the FORTRAN will do the code below pause

I hope this hit can help you

Comment: Pause is deleted from Fortran and it was never really defined was exactly it should do. Remember it was mostly used in the times before the advent of PCs and other computers we know today. Much better is just an empty `read` statement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that your Fortran program is writing to the screen, then the screen disappears when the program completes.  Sort of like a Windows command window.

Try putting a read from console statement after the write.  You don't care what you're reading from the console, but you'll see the results of the write statement in the window while the read waits for console input.

Answer (score 1):

I will guess you are using Windows.

If your executable program is at c:\foo\a.exe, you can open a Windows console with (Start, Run, "cmd"), move to the c:\foo directory using the "cd" command, and then type a.exe at the prompt (or simply "a") to run your program. The output will appear in the Windows console. To redirect the output to a file, you can type "a.exe > some_file.txt". Beginning programmers using Windows should learn a little about the Windows command line, including basic commands such as "cd", "dir", and "findstr".

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same problem.. but then i enabled win16- bit in my win32bit.. which solved the problem

Comment: I am getting same result for different values entered.. why is it so?

Comment: 16-bit Why? What kind of compiler do you use?